# How to display only the confirmation in this tooltip?

Tags: javascript

How to correctly remove the "*Copy to Clipboard*" tooltip on hover but keep the "*Copied: Hello World*" tooltip confirmation after button click.
Here is the code

```
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">

<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
</script>
```

Replaced text from `"Copied: " + copyText.value;` with `""` but getting white space with dark background as per CSS used here:
[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard2)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<br />
<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
</div>

<script>

</script>
```

Comment: I still see "Copy to Clipboard" tooltip on button hover. I want to remove that but see the tooltip on confirmation.